# Unable to launch an activity via a button in android, and am I reusing the AnymoteClientService correctly here?

Tags: android, google-tv

I am getting the following error:

07-11 17:33:27.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1675): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{uk.co.myapp.gtvremote/uk.co.myapp.gtvremote.SlidepuzzleActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Not sure what I have done wrong, welcome any suggestions and/or comments.

Also you may note from the code that I am trying to reuse the AnymoteClientService. I am assuming that the way I have done it here is correct, is it?
:

Manifest excerpt:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="uk.co.myapp.gtvremote"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <service android:name="com.example.google.tv.anymotelibrary.client.AnymoteClientService" >
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.google.tv.anymotelibrary.connection.PairingActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:label="Pairing with TV"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SlidepuzzleActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_slidepuzzle" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
        android:required="true" />

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java excerpt:

```
Button testButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.testButton);

...

testButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SlidepuzzleActivity.class);
//THIS IS WHERE I THINK THE EXCEPTION IS BEING THROWN
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
```

SlidepuzzleActivity.java:

```
public class SlidepuzzleActivity extends Activity implements ClientListener{

    private AnymoteClientService mAnymoteClientService;
    private Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.slidepuzzle);

        ImageButton piece1x1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.piece1x1);
        ImageButton piece1x2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.piece1x2);
        ImageButton piece1x3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.piece1x3);
        ImageButton piece2x1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.piece2x1);
        ImageButton piece2x2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.piece2x2);
        ImageButton piece2x3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.piece2x3);
        ImageButton piece3x1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.piece3x1);
        ImageButton piece3x2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.piece3x2);
        ImageButton piece3x3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.piece3x3);

        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, AnymoteClientService.class);
        bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    }

    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {


        /*
         * ServiceConnection listener methods.
         */
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {

            mAnymoteClientService = ((AnymoteClientService.AnymoteClientServiceBinder) service)
                    .getService();
            mAnymoteClientService.attachClientListener(SlidepuzzleActivity.this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            mAnymoteClientService.detachClientListener(SlidepuzzleActivity.this);
            mAnymoteClientService = null;   
        }

    };

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.slidepuzzle, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(AnymoteSender anymoteSender) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionError() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (mAnymoteClientService != null) {
            mAnymoteClientService.detachClientListener(this);
        }
        unbindService(mConnection);
        super.onDestroy();
    }


}
```

Cheers

REQUESTED STACK TRACE:

```
07-11 17:33:27.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1675): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-11 17:33:27.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1675): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{uk.co.myapp.gtvremote/uk.co.myapp.gtvremote.SlidepuzzleActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-11 17:33:27.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1675):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
07-11 17:33:27.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1675):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
07-11 17:33:27.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1675):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
07-11 17:33:27.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1675):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
07-11 17:33:27.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1675):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-11 17:33:27.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1675):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-11 17:33:27.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1675):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-11 17:33:27.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1675):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-11 17:33:27.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1675):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-11 17:33:27.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1675):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-11 17:33:27.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1675):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-11 17:33:27.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1675):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-11 17:33:27.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1675): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-11 17:33:27.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1675):     at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
07-11 17:33:27.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1675):     at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3175)
07-11 17:33:27.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1675):     at uk.co.myapp.gtvremote.SlidepuzzleActivity.onCreate(SlidepuzzleActivity.java:39)
07-11 17:33:27.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1675):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
07-11 17:33:27.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1675):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
07-11 17:33:27.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1675):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
07-11 17:33:27.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1675):     ... 11 more
```

I have marked in the SlidepuzzleActivity.java excerpt where the exception is being thrown with //THIS IS WHERE I THINK THE EXCEPTION IS BEING THROWN

Comment: Provide the complete stack trace, along with an indication of where in your source code the exception is occurring.

Comment: [Why NullpointerException?](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/why-nullpointerexception-occures-in.html)

Comment: Added trace and the comment  //THIS IS WHERE I THINK THE EXCEPTION IS BEING THROWN where I think its being caused.

Comment: @MYR : Just as an aside, in your manifest, you've set `<intent-filter>` blocks for `MainActivity` and `SlidepuzzleActivity` with action `MAIN` and category `LAUNCHER`. Only one `Activity` should have MAIN/LAUNCHER settings.

Comment: Would this cause my problem? Or is it just a convention to abide by?

Comment: What is line 39 in SlidePuzzle activity, that is the line that is getting null pointer.

Comment: Yes, as you will note from the answer I have accepted below, I needed to set mContext to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see mContext is null; and it may be causing this exception when instantiating the Intent.

Comment: If you look at the log, the null pointer is in the onCreate(), and your instance variable mContext was never initialized when you referenced it...

Comment: Thanks Gabriel Casado! You cannot believe the amount of digging around I have done to work out what I had missed. Is the way I am reusing anymote correct in this?

Comment: @MYR If I understand you question, I think you can just use SlidepuzzleActivity.this to get the Context, but there is nothing wrong (as far as I know) using a variable to keep it, actually the code is more readable.

Comment: Cool, I think I should probably post another separate question about the correct way to reuse the AnymoteService, because I am not sure how I start a new activity and keep the pairing I have, the way I have written the code at the moment, I am going to have to re-connect when my new activity starts... surely a better way!